# Why is $ A^{-1} - P \left( P^T A P \right)^{-1}P^T$ positive definite here?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Assume $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric and positive definite matrix. For matrix $P \in \Bbb R^{n \times m}$ with $m \le n$ and $\text{rank}(P)=m$, is the following matrix positive definite?

$$ A^{-1} - P \left( P^T A P \right)^{-1}P^T$$

If it is not positive definite, can we say that this matrix is positive semidefinite? Any idea is appreciated.

---

This expression seems something like projection, but how can we prove it?

Comment: @daw You are right, and I have modified question. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The matrix is indeed positive semidefinite. Note that
$$
A^{-1} - P \left( P^T A P \right)^{-1}P^T = \\
A^{-1/2}\left[I -  [A^{1/2}P] \left( [A^{1/2}P]^T [A^{1/2}P] \right)^{-1}[A^{1/2}P]^T\right]A^{-1/2}. \tag{*}
$$
For the matrix $B = A^{1/2}$, the matrix $M = I - B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T$ is positive semidefinite since it satisfies $M = MM^T$ (in fact, $M$ is the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $B$). As equation $(*)$ above indicates, your matrix is equal to $[A^{-1/2}]^T M[A^{-1/2}]$ and is therefore positive semidefinite.

(In general, if $M$ is positive semidefinite, then $C^TMC$ must be positive semidefinite).

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. It is a very nice proof!

Answer (score 5):

The matrix is not positive definite. We have
$$
P^TA\cdot ( A^{-1} - P(P^TAP)^{-1}P^T) =0.
$$
If the matrix would be positive definite, then it would be invertible, then the above equation would imply $P=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If we relax the condition to positive semidefinite, is it true?